# Laravel Homestead - Connection timeout after re-up on hostname

Tags: php, laravel-5, homestead

I'm having a 'problem' with Laravel Homestead that only occurs when my computer has been running for quite a while, and I re-up with vagrant after the VM has been shut down earlier.

The routine:

1. Power up PC/windows
2. Vagrant up
3. Everything is fine immediatly and I can access with "http://sitename.local" or "192.168.10.10" in browser
4. Vagrant Halt
5. Vagrant up again hours/day later
6. **All boot procedures goes well, but a timeout error occurs in any browser for the site when I access it through the "http://sitename.local" hostname. I tried provisioning and restarting vm.**

**However**, I can ssh into the VM and do stuff. I can also access the site if I instead use the local ip 127.0.0.1:8000.

*My question is:*

Why can't it resolve "http://sitename.local" at a later time when I re-up the VM, but no problem doing so only after my PC has just started up?

I would really like to understand what is happening even though I technically can access it with the localhost ip instead.

Thank you.

Comment: Cowboy guesswork here but are you able to inspect the network settings of the homestead instance and see if it changes the second time you power it up? I'm probably wrong though

Comment: can't see any difference I'm afraid. I'm suspecting that it's windows in some form or another that makes this happen. I'm running WIN 10, pro.

Comment: Windows is a bit nasty to do real development work on in my HO, haven't you considering switching to a linux/mac environment? Perhaps you could dual boot it (I do)

Comment: Have you looked up any docs for vagrant to see if there's any way you can debug that instance?

Comment: @Jonathan Indeed, I love windows for many things, but web/server dev is not one of them, even though it works alright. I'm definitely in to changing up to a Linux env for that purpose alone. I've messed around with a linux VM and I quite liked it. installing Node packages w/ windows is a mess, although the dependency system in Node is a mess as well.

Comment: @Jonathan I'm looking into debugging now, but I'm still convinced windows is messing it up with the host resolving - although I do not know why. Both debugging in vagrant and looking into the windows event viewer.

Comment: Good luck! And I totally agree- in more ways than one - developing in windows can be a real PITA.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem? I'm dealing with exactly the same thing now...

Comment: I can't remember what "fixed" it, but surely it must have been windows. Whatever it was, it's fixed now. Sorry I didn't post what helped it - kinda forgot. Don't think any *one* thing solved it though. I updated all VM related software, purged all browser caches, house-cleaning in windows (dns, temps, registry, etc). Also deleted old virtualbox boxes, updated to latest, re-did all vagrant/homestead initial setup. Still convinced it was some silly DNS lookup issue, as I have configured so many things towards the localhost ip over the years... Sorry I could not be of more help.